# Clearing Custom Tool file property in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, t4, texttemplate

Is there any way to prevent prevent a custom tool from running or remove the custom tool for a file type per project in Visual Studio? In my example I would like to add a file to my project with an extension (.tt) that Visual Studio assoicates with the TextTemplatingFileGenerator. I would like to not have to go into the file properties and clear the Custom Tool property as well as clean up any work done by the single file generator that runs when adding the file to my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the .csproj file where the file appears you can set Generator to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn off the automatic assigning of the custom tool property to .tt files, you can delete the registry key below: (usual caveats about backing up your registry before hacking apply)

The guid is for the C# project system - browse the other guids that are its peers for the VB project system.

32-bit
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Generators{FAE04EC1-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}.tt

64-bit
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Generators{FAE04EC1-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}.tt

Comment: Yeah, this will work but be careful like you said because this disables the single file generator for .tt files for every project you create.