# How do I remove a custom tool from visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, protobuf-net

I've installed the protobuf-net ProtoBufTool custom tool into visual studio to automatically generate .cs file from protocol buffers files. I want to be able to build my project using msbuild for continuous integration and have moved over to using a python script to generate the files.

So how do you remove a custom tool from visual studio?

I've removed it from `Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ItemTemplates\Visual C#` which is where I installed it. I've searched for it in the registry and the GAC. I've tried removing it from the file properties in VS and it keeps coming back. I don't want to nuke my machine from orbit!

**Edit:** I've found the correct registry key now to disable the tool (see [Clearing Custom Tool file property in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372567/clearing-custom-tool-file-property-in-visual-studio-2010)) but I'd still be interested to know if there's a better workflow for managing custom tools

Comment: Did the uninstaller not work? Minor note: the templates are completely separate to the custom tool.

Comment: I think top gun can help me here:

I'm holding on too tight.

I've lost the edge. I'm sorry, sir.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try:

- Tools -> Add-in Managers
- Tools -> Extension Manager

Answer (score 0):

"Tools -> External tools" menu can help you.

Answer (score 0):

As Marc pointed out there's a perfectly good uninstaller for just this situation.